# iOS - Changing tabbar badge from other class

Tags: ios, xcode, tabbar, badge

I've searched a lot but could not find an answer and therefore decided to ask you :).

I have an application with some views. After logging in I create a UITabBarController with 3 tabs.

Now I wish to change the second tab's badge based on how many notifications the user has.

This core works when called in the viewdidload method:

```
NSString *badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [cacheNotifications count]];
if([cacheNotifications count] != 0){
    [[[[[self tabBarController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex: 1] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:badgeValue];
}
```

However, I have a daemon running in the background that checks for notifications every 30 seconds. It would be great if I could change the badge from this daemon.

When I call something like this:

```
PlatformViewController *theInstance = [[PlatformViewController alloc] init];
    [theInstance updateNotificationsBadge];
```

It does call the function but does not update the badge. With or without the performSelectorOnMainThread.

**updateNotificationsBadge:**

```
-(void) updateNotificationsBadge{
NSString *badgeValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [cacheNotifications count]];
NSLog(@"Length here is: %i", [cacheNotifications count]);
if([cacheNotifications count] > 0){
    NSLog(@"call..");
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setNotification:)
                                    withObject:badgeValue
                                 waitUntilDone:YES];


}
```

}

```
-(void)setNotification:(NSString*)badge{
NSLog(@"Called. %@", badge);
[[[[[self tabBarController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex: 1] tabBarItem] setBadgeValue:badge];
```

}

How could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

cacheNotifications is a global variable declared in globalVars.m. It does not get reinitialized when I call a new instance.

I call the code below from daemonClass.m

```
PlatformViewController *theInstance = [[PlatformViewController alloc] init];
[theInstance updateNotificationsBadge];
```

Comment: Ok. Did you try as I said in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new instance for `platformViewController`, you need to use **existing reference**. When you create a new one, `cacheNotification` array would not be `initialized` and no `contents` in it. So it will always **returns 0**.

and `UITabBarController` is a `containerViewController` contains all the `viewControllers`. So you don't need to change the tab `badgeValue` from the other class. **You can simply change it from any class.**

and in your `setNotification:` method, change the `badgeValue` like this.

```
[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setBadgeValue:badge];
```

Comment: Okay, I get that and it does indeed work if I call the code from any class that the tabbarcontroller is a parent of.

But I have this class daemonClass.m that runs a piece of code every 30 seconds that checks for notifications. It is a class-method ( +(void) ). How would I update the badge from this method?

Comment: Write a method to update the tab bar badge value in the appdelegate and call that method from your daemonclass class method. I mentioned that you can call from any class.(That means any viewcontrollers which is inside the tab bar controller).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same instance of class rather creating the new one. Which destroy the previous value. I would recommend please use NSNotificationCenter to post notification when you get a badge which will implement void getter and setter method of badge in `platformViewController`class. then no instance would be destroy.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I  really don't know exactly your problem, but what I think I would use a subclass of nsobject and in each viewController I'd change the badge. Something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/2000162

Answer (score 0):

```
func setBadge(){
        let viewconrollers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers
        viewconrollers![3].tabBarItem.badgeValue = "Your String value"
        viewconrollers![3].tabBarItem.badgeColor = UIColor.green
    }
//call setBadge() method from view controller's viewdidload method.

// select your give number it the view controllers array for providing badge on the desired tab
```